# Why can't I reuse an iterator?ListIterator class initially with reference "itr",and is not accessible for another iteration.Can anyonehelpmewith this?

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing, collections, iterator

```
 import java.util.*;
 public class Main
 {
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 ArrayList <Integer> Array_List = new ArrayList();
 Array_List.add(100);
 Array_List.add(200);

 //A listiterator to check previous element accessing 

 ListIterator <Integer>  itr =Array_List.listIterator();

 //Accessing and printing elements with hasNext() method

 while(itr.hasNext()){
 System.out.println("Index of elements : "+itr.nextIndex()+
                        " and element is "+itr.next()+" ");
 }
 System.out.println();
 Array_List.add(1,250);
 Array_List.remove(2);

 //Accessing using the same iterator reference to print
 previous elements

 while(itr.hasPrevious())
 {   
 System.out.println("I can access index but elements are not printed 
 here...");
 System.out.println("Index of previous element is 
 :"+itr.previousIndex());
 System.out.println(itr.previous());}                   
}
}
```

Output:
Index of elements : 0 and element is 100
Index of elements : 1 and element is 200

I can access index but elements are not printed here...
Index of previous element is :1

Comment: Please [edit] the post and format your code properly.

Answer (score 2):

Iterators are invalidated as soon as you modify the backing list any way *other* than using the iterator itself.

> ...if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

These lines break your iterator:

```
 Array_List.add(1,250);
 Array_List.remove(2);
```

You will need to create a new, fresh iterator.